# The zero of a continuously differentiable function is zero-measured

Tags: real-analysis

I'm tring to prove the following statement:

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable, and for any $(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\neq 0
$$
then show that:
$$
E=\{(x,y):f(x,y)=0\}
$$
is a zero-measured set in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It's easy to see that $0$ in the definition of $E$ can be replaced by any real number $c$.             I have tried to integrate the two variable function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)$ and then applied the Fubini theorem but with no valuable findings. Can anybody give me some hints on proving this statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The desired conclusion can be obtained under the weaker assumption that
$$
f(x_0,y_0)=0 \; \Longrightarrow \;  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\neq 0  \,.
$$

For every real $b$, consider the function
$g_b:{\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}$ defined by $g_b(t)=f(t,t+b)$.
For every $t$, the chain rule and the hypothesis give  $$g_b(t)=0 \; \Longrightarrow \; g_b'(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,t+b)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,t+b)\ne 0 \,,$$
so the zeros of $g_b$ are isolated, whence they form a countable set (at most). Thus the set $E$ of zeros of $f$  intersects every line of the form
$\{y=x+b\}$ in a set of zero length, so Fubini's theorem implies that $E$ has zero area.

To formalize the last step, you may want to consider the (area preserving)  rotation $R$ by $45$ degrees, observe that $R(E)$ intersects every vertical line in a set of zero length, and deduce that
$R(E)$ (and hence also $E$) has zero area.